# How would you parse a url in Ruby to get the main domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, url, dns

I want to be able to parse any URL with Ruby to get the main part of the domain without the `www` (just the `example.com`)

Comment: Ruby does not handle hostname matching correctly under all conditions when matching an end entity server cert. I'm aware of some unexpected and nonsensical results.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This should work with pretty much any URL:

```
# URL always gets parsed twice
def get_host_without_www(url)
  url = "http://#{url}" if URI.parse(url).scheme.nil?
  host = URI.parse(url).host.downcase
  host.start_with?('www.') ? host[4..-1] : host
end
```

Or:

```
# Only parses twice if url doesn't start with a scheme
def get_host_without_www(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  uri = URI.parse("http://#{url}") if uri.scheme.nil?
  host = uri.host.downcase
  host.start_with?('www.') ? host[4..-1] : host
end
```

You may have to `require 'uri'`.

Comment: That probably won't work if `url` is just `www.example.com`, URI doesn't react well to URIs that don't have schemes.

Comment: You can get around that by checking `u.scheme` right after `u = URI.parse(url)` and then adding a scheme if necessary and reparsing.

Comment: I think these are getting too complex. This should work: `URI('http://www.example.com').host.match(/[^\.]+\.\w+$/).to_s`.

Comment: @Chip hey your regex can't check `ccTLD` If `URI('http://www.example.co.kr').host.match(/[^\.]+\.\w+$/).to_s` coded, then `=> "co.kr"` is outputted

Answer (score 91):

Please note **there is no algorithmic method of finding the highest level at which a domain may be registered for a particular top-level domain** (the policies differ with each registry), the only method is to create a list of all top-level domains and the level at which domains can be registered.

This is the reason why the [Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/) exists.

I'm the author of [PublicSuffix](http://www.simonecarletti.com/code/publicsuffix/), a Ruby library that decomposes a domain into the different parts.

Here's an example

```
require 'uri/http'

uri = URI.parse("http://toolbar.google.com")
domain = PublicSuffix.parse(uri.host)
# => "toolbar.google.com"
domain.domain
# => "google.com"

uri = URI.parse("http://www.google.co.uk")
domain = PublicSuffix.parse(uri.host)
# => "www.google.co.uk"
domain.domain
# => "google.co.uk"
```

Comment: Is the last `domain.domain #=> "google.com"` a mistake or am I not understanding something??

Comment: No, it's not a mistake. The first `domain` is a variable, the second is the method call. The variable can be called whatever you want.

Comment: "This is the reason why the Public Suffix List exists..." - I don't believe the 'main' domain and an entry in the PSL are the same thing. The PSL includes gTLDs, ccTLDs and paths for cookies. The cookie paths are not needed to determine the 'main' domain, and it might cause an incorrect result.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti My original comment was a while ago, but what I meant was that in the last example `.co.uk`, becomes `.com` all of a sudden.

Comment: I would rename `domain.domain` to `domain.name`

Answer (score 4):

Just a short note: to overcome the second parsing of the url from Mischas second example, you could make a string comparison instead of URI.parse.

```
# Only parses once
def get_host_without_www(url)
  url = "http://#{url}" unless url.start_with?('http')
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  host = uri.host.downcase
  host.start_with?('www.') ? host[4..-1] : host
end
```

The downside of this approach is, that it is limiting the url to http(s) based urls, which is widely the standard. But if you will use it more general (f.e. for ftp links) you have to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

[Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable#example-usage) is probably the right answer in 2018, especially [uses the PublicSuffix gem to parse domains](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/blob/0e640ca64ab461d43bcf0d5515adc8f63da76872/lib/addressable/uri.rb#L1176:L1178).

However, I need to do this kind of parsing in multiple places, from various data sources, and found it a bit verbose to use repeatedly. So I created a wrapper around it, [Adomain](https://github.com/samnissen/adomain):

```
require 'adomain'

Adomain["https://toolbar.google.com"]
# => "toolbar.google.com"

Adomain["https://www.google.com"]
# => "google.com"

Adomain["stackoverflow.com"]
# => "stackoverflow.com"
```

I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that works better with .co.uk and .com.fr - type domains

```
domain = uri.host[/[^.\s\/]+\.([a-z]{3,}|([a-z]{2}|com)\.[a-z]{2})$/]
```

Comment: returns nil on this one: https://www.moebel-turflon.de/karriere/jobs/136

Answer (score 0):

if the URL is in format `http://www.google.com`, then you could do something like:

```
a = 'http://www.google.com'
puts a.split(/\./)[1] + '.' + a.split(/\./)[2]
```

Or

```
a =~ /http:\/\/www\.(.*?)$/
puts $1
```

Comment: definitely not - it really depends on your input - are your receiving just an url at a time as input? do the urls have relative paths? do they always come with `www` as a subdomain? do they always have a subdomain? are they all `http` urls or you get urls with `https`, `ftp`, etc? and there are many more questions that could be asked - this is just to get you started :)

Comment: That wouldn't work for a UK domains `co.uk` for example