# How do I get just the sitename from url in ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, url

I have a url such as:

```
http://www.relevantmagazine.com/life/relationship/blog/23317-pursuing-singleness
```

And would like to extract just **relevantmagazine** from it.

Currently I have:

```
@urlroot = URI.parse(@link.url).host
```

But it returns **www.relevantmagazine.com**  can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a gem for this might be overkill, but anyway: There's a handy gem called [domainatrix](https://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix) that can extract the sitename for your while dealing with things like two element top-level domains and more.

```
url = Domainatrix.parse("http://www.pauldix.net")
url.url       # => "http://www.pauldix.net" (the original url)
url.public_suffix       # => "net"
url.domain    # => "pauldix"
url.canonical # => "net.pauldix"

url = Domainatrix.parse("http://foo.bar.pauldix.co.uk/asdf.html?q=arg")
url.public_suffix       # => "co.uk"
url.domain    # => "pauldix"
url.subdomain # => "foo.bar"
url.path      # => "/asdf.html?q=arg"
url.canonical # => "uk.co.pauldix.bar.foo/asdf.html?q=arg"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is a bit overkill for this but could be useful in the future

Comment: It certainly seems so, until your want to parse `pilot.consulting.aero` only to realize that `consulting.aero` is the top level domain. :-D

Comment: you need overkill tho... domains are complex... you'd need a library with every known tld so that you know everything that could possible come before your "domain" its impossible to figure out how many entities come before your domain.. but you're know your always one or two steps away from your tld..

Answer (score 2):

how about

@urlroot = URI.parse(@link.url).host.gsub("www.", "").split(".")[0]

Comment: Thank you but this didn't strip of the .com, .co.uk etc from the end.

Comment: oo i missed that requirement

Comment: fixed ish..... still what if u had www.blah.goo.arch.boom.myactualdomain.co.uk your gonna need a super powerful regex..... that takes all these into account if you wanna get super crazy i'd gear it to your actual requirements... do u expect super crazy subdomains like that?

Comment: That is true, even in my own answer the I would get the first subdomain so doesn't solve what I was wanting

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
regex = %r{http://[w]*[\.]*[^/|$]*}
```

If you had the following url strings, it gives the following:

```
url = 'http://www.google.com/?q=blah'
url.scan(regex) => ["http://www.google.com"]

url = 'http://google.com/?q=blah'
url.scan(regex) => ["http://google.com"]

url = 'http://google.com'
url.scan(regex) => ["http://google.com"]

url = 'http://foo.bar.pauldix.co.uk/asdf.html?q=arg'
url.scan(regex) => ["http://foo.bar.pauldix.co.uk"]
```

It's not perfect, but it will strip out everything but the prefix and the host name. You can then easily clean up the prefix with some other code knowing now you only need to look for an `http://` or `http://www.` at the beginning of the string. Another thought is you may need to tweak the regex I gave you a little if you are also going to parse `https://`. I hope this helps you get started!

Edit:

I reread the question, and realized my answer doesn't really do what you asked. I suppose it might be helpful to know if you know if the urls you're parsing will have a set format like always have the www. If it does, you could use a regular expression that extracts everything between the first and second period in the url. If not, perhaps you could tweak my regex so that it's everything between the / or www. and the first period. That might be the easiest way to get just the site name with none of the www. or the .com or .au.uk and such.

Revised regex:

```
regex = %r{http://[w]*[\.]*[^\.]*}
url = 'http://foo.bar.pauldix.co.uk/asdf.html?q=arg'
url.scan(regex) => ["http://foo"]
```

It'll be weird. If you use the regex stuff, you'll probably have to do it incrementally to clean up the url to extract the part you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just split it?

```
 URI.parse(@link.url).host.split('.')[1]
```

Keep in mind that some registered domains may have more than one component to the registered country domain, like `.co.uk` or `.co.jp` or `.com.au` for example.

Comment: You answer also assumes that the URL contains a host name.

Comment: Yes that wouldn't work if the url came in like - 
http://relevantmagazine.com/life/relationship/blog/23317-pursuing-singleness as I would have **relevantmagazine.com** returned

Comment: Relative links would also be problematic, like `/example` instead of `http://example.com/example`.

Comment: @tadman it would be but in my use case I would only be dealing with absolute links.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer inspired by tadman's answer and [the answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674230/how-would-you-parse-a-url-in-ruby-to-get-the-main-domain?rq=1)

```
@urlroot = URI.parse(item.url).host
@urlroot = @urlroot.start_with?('www.') ? @urlroot[4..-1] : @urlroot
@urlroot = @urlroot.split('.')[0]
```

First line get the host,  second line gets removes the www. if they is one and third line get everything before the next dot.

Comment: This still didn't answer it, as a comment in another answer pointed out - if the link was http://subdomain.domain.com   I would get subdomain instead of the domain part.