# creating a helper method to remove http or https from the beginning of a url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I'm accepting user input in the form of web links, e.g.: `http://google.com`

In my database I don't want to store the `http://` prefix, or `https://`. I was going to do a string search at the beginning of the URL for those two things.

I feel like this is something rails/ruby might do out of the box, does anyone know of such a function?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674230/how-would-you-parse-a-url-in-ruby-to-get-the-main-domain) might help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [document](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#M001446):

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI("http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413")
uri.scheme   #=> "http"
uri.host     #=> "foo.com"
uri.path     #=> "/posts"
uri.query    #=> "id=30&limit=5"
uri.fragment #=> "time=1305298413"
```

Or,

```
require 'uri'

URI.split("http://www.ruby-lang.org/")
# => ["http", nil, "www.ruby-lang.org", nil, nil, "/", nil, nil, nil]
```

Comment: @sawa fwiw notice in your last example that the first "?" necessary to maintain functional query params is dropped.

Comment: @seanomlor You are right. I just remove the example.