# How to get domain from URL without using URI Parser. I want to done it using regex

Tags: ruby

i'm trying to write regular expression  which returns the domain from the URL.
for example:-

```
"http://github.com" # => 'github'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with @Arup Rakshit's solution. However if you really want a regexp, why not using

```
/^http:\/\/(.+)\.[a-z]{2,3}/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Ruby's stdlib [`URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#module-URI-label-Basic+example)

```
require 'uri'
s = "http://github.com"
URI(s).host # => "github.com"
```

Also look into this [How would you parse a url in Ruby to get the main domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674230/how-would-you-parse-a-url-in-ruby-to-get-the-main-domain).

Some modification to the method in the linked answer :

```
require 'uri'

def get_domain(url)
  url = "http://#{url}" if URI.parse(url).scheme.nil?
  host = URI.parse(url).hostname
  host.sub(/^www\./i, '')
end

s = "http://github.com"
get_domain(s) # => "github.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 for @Arup Rakshit's answer, it's almost always better to use existing solutions.

Regarding your question. This regexp will handle both http and https protocols, remove www (other subdomains will be preserved), remove a tld of any length (and query string too):

```
'https://www.my.rubular.com/' =~ /\Ahttps?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)\.[^\.\/]+/
$1

# => "my.rubular"
```

this regexp will omit any subdomain and keep only domain

```
'https://www.my.rubular.com/' =~ /\Ahttps?:\/\/(?:[^\/]+\.)*([^\/]+)\.[^\.\/]+/
$1

# => "rubular"
```

and here is a funny way to achieve your goal too:

```
'https://www.rubular.com/'.split('//').last.split('/').first.split('.')[-2]

# => "rubular"
```

ps. notice this about the accepted answer:

```
'http://www.my.rubular.com/xxx.yyy.zzz/qwerty.fff/' =~ /^http:\/\/(.+)\.[a-z]{2,3}/
$1

# => "www.my.rubular.com/xxx.yyy.zzz/qwerty"
```