# Split URL based on characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I was wondering how best to go about splitting the following string by `/` but ignoring certain characters

So my string will look like this

```
url = http://10.0.3.2/i/av/Genymotionvbox86p/android/10~3~1/0/-/-/a3306aa6~0346~4ad5~bdf5~1bc7c20a88ab/0/test~page/-/-/video/live/-/one_hd/-/0/1/0~0/-/0~0/0~0/?trace=skwthffdsy
```

I want to split by `/` ignoring the `http://` and the query string at the end, the desired outcome would look like

```
["i", "av", "Genymotionvbox86p", "android", "10~3~1", "0", "-", "-",
  "a3306aa6~0346~4ad5~bdf5~1bc7c20a88ab", "0", "test~page", "-", "-",
  "video", "live", "-", "one_hd", "-", "0", "1", "0~0", "-", "0~0", "0~0"]
```

So at the moment `url.split('/')` gets me so far but its the excluding or certain characters I am stuck on

Maybe using `scan` would serve me better?

Comment: Do you *know* that the URL wil always be in that format? Will the "http(s)://" always be present? Will there always be a "/" before any params at the end? `url.split('/')[3..-2]` is a trivial solution, but won't work for many possible URL formats.

Comment: yes the url `should` always be in that format, i cant envisage  a time when the http(s) would appear anywhere else. I thought about taking the url and then using `gsub` to remove what i dont want, but after adding more parameters to the string the solution does seem to still work

Comment: Are you sure??!!... "www.google.com/search?q=example" is a valid URL, which does not have either of these properties. The `split('/')[3..-2]` method will fail for this.

Comment: In fact, even **worse** is if the query parameters contain "/" too! E.g. ""www.google.com/search?q=what/about/this" will give you an even worse result with the `split` method.

Comment: @TomLord: well, `URI` from stdlib falls flat on its face in absence of the scheme part. Treats domain as part of path.

Comment: @TomLord `www.google.com/search?q=example` is not a valid URL. The scheme part is obligatory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you parse a url in Ruby to get the main domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674230/how-would-you-parse-a-url-in-ruby-to-get-the-main-domain)

Comment: @michau: relative urls are also a thing

Comment: @SergioTulentsev But relative URLs don't have the host part, so if we treat `www.google.com/search?q=example` as such, `www.google.com` is a part of the path, not the host.

Comment: @michau: that's true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
require 'uri'
URI(url).path.sub(%r{^/}, "").split("/")
```

**Edit**: why use `gsub` when shorter and faster `sub` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this?

```
url.split('/')[3..-2]
```

`[3..-2]` means scope of array, it takes all elements from index `3` to index `-2`

```
-2
```

means one before last

Comment: thanks, would you mind explaining the `[3..-2]` please ?

Comment: See: `ary[range]`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now

Comment: If query part contains slashes, e.g. `?trace=skw/thf/f/ds`, this method won't work correctly.

Comment: @Richlewis: you should use the proper tool for the job (uri parsing libs). Hardcoding array offsets like this is very fragile and is not at all future-proof. Depends on contents of your query string very much.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev I will look at uri parsing libs