# Trying to extract only the domain name

Tags: ruby, parsing, split, uri

I am trying to get only the domain name (ex.: only 'google' not the .com or .uk etc).
I've encountered a simple solution but it says I can't use it if domain is nil (???)
here's the error message:
`main.rb:7:in`domain_name': undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Here's my code:

```
require 'uri'

def domain_name(url)
  URI.parse(url).host.split('.').first
end
```

Please help me find this solution. Thanks

Comment: how do you intend to handle nil value? I will just add `return if url.nil?` before parsing the URL if it's allowed,  otherwise `raise StandardError, "url is nil" if url.nil?` to terminate if nil may not be allowed at all cost.

Comment: @darkash check my answer. `host` can be `nil` without `url` being `nil`

Comment: @AnaMaríaMartínezGómez you're right

Comment: Can you please add some example input? Because picking the first part from the hostname will not always work – for example for `www.google.com.au`?

Comment: doing some tests it seems that if an url doesn't have http:// at the beginning url.host doesn't work, try adding http:// before the url that you have

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would you parse a url in Ruby to get the main domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674230/how-would-you-parse-a-url-in-ruby-to-get-the-main-domain)

Comment: What should the result be for `smtp.google.co.uk`?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if host is `nil` before calling split by assigning it to a variable:

```
def domain_name(url)
  host = URI(url).host
  split('.').first if host
end
```

If you prefer, you can also use the the safe navigation operator`&`  (introduced in Ruby 2.3). The following code produces the same result as the previous one:

```
def domain_name(url)
  URI.parse(url).host&.split('.')&.first
end
```

Note that there are reasons not to use this operator (the code is not readable, difficult to debug bugs, etc.). Check https://www.theguild.nl/5-reasons-not-to-use-safe-navigation-operators for more details.

Those solutions return `nil` in case host is not found. You can also return an empty string (or something else) doing something like that:

```
def domain_name(url)
  host = URI(url).host
  host ? split('.').first : ''
end
```

All this solutions only help handle the `nil`, but you may actually want to check [How would you parse a url in Ruby to get the main domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674230/how-would-you-parse-a-url-in-ruby-to-get-the-main-domain)

Last, note that`host` can return `nil` even if the `url` is not `nil`:

```
URI.parse("hello").host #=> nil
```

Comment: @Eddie which of the solutions are you trying? If you have an if for `nil` values or use the `&` operator, the method is not even called if you have a `nil`. Are you sure it is the same error in the same place?

Comment: I'm still getting a no method error and it doesn't pass any test now. but not the same error, sorry about that.
`domain_name': undefined method `split' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Comment: @Eddie I think the problem is that you have written `.&` instead `&.`

Comment: not really. the problem was with one of the tests. the URI.parse(url).host was not working if the parameter didn't have 'http://' it would return nil right away so the following split method wound't work at all. Here's what I did: 
```
require 'uri'

def domain_name(url)
  if url.match(/http/)
   URI(url).host.split('.').first
  else
    url.gsub("www.", "").split(".")[0]
  end
end
```
it passes all tests

Comment: I just posted the solution below. Thanks @Ana.

Comment: @Eddie you should have include these details in your question. I only answered to how to solve the concrete problem you mention of managing nil. But this seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674230/how-would-you-parse-a-url-in-ruby-to-get-the-main-domain